# Where to put the doxygen comment blocks for an internal library - in H or in CPP files?

Tags: documentation, comments, doxygen

The common sense tells that the Doxygen comment blocks have to be put in the header files where the classes, structs, enums, functions, declarations are. I agree that this is a sound argument for a libraries that are mean to be distributed without its source (only headers and libs with object code).

BUT...I've been thinking of the exact opposite approach when I'm developing an internal to the company (or as a side project for myself) library that will be used with its full source code. What I propose is to put the large comment blocks in the implementations files (HPP, INL, CPP, etc) in order NOT to clutter the inteface of the classes and functions declared in the header.

**Pros:**

- Less clutter in the header files, only categorizing of the functions can be added.
- The comment blocks that are previewed when Intellisense for example is used doesn't clash - this is a defect that I have observed when I have a comment block for a function in the .H file and have its inline definition in the same .H file but included from .INL file.

**Cons:**

- (The obvious one) The comment blocks are not in the header files where the declarations are.

So, what do you think and possibly suggest?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Put the documentation where people will read and write it as they are using and working on the code.

Class comments go in front of classes, method comments in front of methods.

That is the best way to make sure things are maintained. It also keeps your header files relatively lean and avoids the *touching* issue of people updating method docs causing headers to be dirty and triggering rebuilds. I have actually known people use that as an excuse for writing documentation *later!*

Comment: I've had a painful reminder of why docs in headers should be avoided - was told by a senior VP to put method comments in the class declaration and found myself actually saving up comment edits for later because hitting those headers triggers a 45 minute build time!

Comment: Not downvoting, just questioning: If I'm trying to figure out what an API (even an internal one) does, I'd rather not have to open up the .cpp and wade through all the code to find the documentation. I'll admit it would be a pain if you document more than just the client's view of what the method is doing (like *how* it does it), but you shouldn't be doing that anyway, right?

Comment: The whole point of using Doxygen to generate your documentation is to have the generated documentation accessible. We have an internal web server where the Doxygen output goes and we can then use links to pages on that server in discussions. That also ties together class or method documentation with additional pages discussing broader design issues.

Comment: Deciding how public the implementation discussion should be is an interesting issue. Certainly if there's a particular algorithm or side-effects, I would prefer to know about them as a client of the library. Sometimes only the maintainer should know and Doxygen has an easy way to mark conditional sections, so you might generate different docs for different viewpoints.

Comment: Not only that. Documentation in the headers pollutes them and make unsuitable as an api-cheatsheet. I often take a brief look in the header for a reminder of some interface details. And if the header is polluted with the comments it becomes difficult to extract useful information quickly. If I want exhaustive documentation I'd refer to generated docs if the source is not available.

Comment: @AndyDent that's your Editor's problem, and is no reason to **not** write doc-comments in header, I mean, my Editor has "Save as old" option/extension, which does simply "Save" on same file, but sets modified-date to "2000-1-1" (this works because compiler does only check modified-date, not hash of the file).

Comment: I think you suggest commenting above the _definition_; not the _declaration_. In the context of the question and for the common case where the class is defined in the header and the methods are defined in the .cpp, you would comment the class in the header and the methods in the .cpp.

Comment: "where people will read and write it": I don't think that's possible. When I want to learn how to use a class, I read the header since it's shorter. So, for leaning/reading the header is the better place. I do agree that comments are more likely to be maintained when above the definition (.cpp in my example). I do like the comment "point of using Doxygen ... is to have the generated documentation accessible". Also, a good/smart IDE will find and show me the comments based on context. Here's my take away: with good tooling it's better to put the comments at the definition.

Answer (score 98):

I like to make use of the fact that names can be documented in multiple places.

In the header file, I write a brief description of the method, and document all its parameters - these are less likely to change than the implementation of the method itself, and if they do, then the function prototype needs to be changed in any case.

I put long-format documentation in the source files next to the actual implementation, so the details can be changed as the method evolves.

For example:

**mymodule.h**

```cpp
/// @brief This method adds two integers.
/// @param a First integer to add.
/// @param b Second integer to add.
/// @return The sum of both parameters.
int add(int a, int b);
```

**mymodule.cpp**

```cpp
/// This method uses a little-known variant of integer addition known as
/// Sophocles' Scissors. It optimises the function's performance on many
/// platforms that we may or may not choose to target in the future.
/// @TODO make sure I implemented the algorithm correctly with some unit tests.
int add(int a, int b) {
  return b + a;
}
```

Comment: I like this method, but it seems to be incompatible with AUTOBRIEF. I would be interested to know if there's a configuration workaround to eliminate the multiple briefs that are produced.

Comment: I also like this method, it provides a good balance in implementation.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this method on my machine, using Doxygen 1.8.15. The parameter documentation does not appear, only the brief and detailed descriptions.

Comment: Addendum: Changing the placement of the detailed description to inside of the block of the function made this work for me. The description is now appended to the end of the descriptions in the header docs.

Comment: Good in theory, but leads to duplication of information :(

Answer (score 24):

Having comments in the header means that all users of a class must be recompiled if a comment is changed. For a large projects, coders will be less inclined to update comments in headers if they risk spending the next 20min rebuilding everything.

And.. since you're supposed to read the html doc and not browse through the code for documentation, it's not a large problem that the comment blocks are more difficult to locate in the source files.

Comment: Correct, but it is a large problem if it's a dynamic library retrieved from an artifactory and you don't have the source files :-)

Answer (score 15):

*Headers:*
Easier to read the comments since there is less other "noise" when looking at the files.

*Source:*
Then you have the actual functions available for reading while looking at the comments.

We just use all global functions commented in headers and local functions commented in source.  If you want you can also include the copydoc command to insert the documentation in multiple places without having to write it several times ( better for maintenance )

You could however also get the results copied over to different file documentation with a simple command. E.g. :-

My file1.h

```
/**
 * \brief Short about function
 *
 * More about function
 */
WORD my_fync1(BYTE*);
```

MY file1.c

```
/** \copydoc my_func1 */
WORD my_fync1(BYTE* data){/*code*/}
```

Now you get the same documentation on both functions.

This gives you less noise in the code files at the same time you get the documentation written in one place presented in several places in the final output.

Comment: when does the block get copied?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using QtCreator for programming. A very useful trick consists in Ctrl-Clicking on a function or method to get the declaration in the header file.

When the method is commented in the header file, you can quickly find the information you are looking for. So for me, comments should be located in the header file!

Answer (score 2):

Usually I put documentation for interface (\param, \return) in .h file and documentation for implementation (\details) in .c/.cpp/.m file. Doxygen groups everything in the function/method documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I put everything in the header file.

I document everything, but only generally extract the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ sometimes implementation can be split between header and .cpp modules.  Here it seems cleaner to put it documentation into the header file as that is the only place that all public functions and methods are guaranteed.